# i want to display ads in a foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have some items i want displayed in the view, my per page is set to 15, so each page displays 15 items, but i want to display ads in the middle of the loop, after maybe 4 items displayed, I've tried to put an if statement in the foreach loop to control the display, it displays the first 3 values, but when i put the div for the ad, it loops too, can someone please tell me what to do, or point me in the right direction?? thanks, here is my code so far:

```
      <?php
        $counter1 = 0; 
    //the foreach loop that retrieves the values from the controller    
    foreach($records as $record){

//an if statement to display the first 4 items..
                 if ($counter1 <= 3){ 
                                ?>

                                <div class='box-scene'>
                                   <div class='dbox'>
                                      <div class='front face'>
                                         <a href="#"><img src="images/newtag.png"></a>
                                      </div>
                                      <a style="font-size:15px;" href="<?php echo base_url();?>music/<?php echo $record->url; ?>">
                                      <div class="side face">
                                         <span>
                                            <?php echo $record->name; ?>
                                         </span>
                                      </div>
                                      </a>
                                   </div>
                                </div>


                            <?php 
                              $counter1++;
                            } 
                            ?>



                 <div style="width:200px; height:200px; float:left; display:inline-block; margin: 0 12.5px 20px 12.5px;">
               <div id="ad_200_200">  
               </div>
            </div>
 <!-- this div displays more than once, i dont know where to place it
  for it to display after the first 3 items -->


                    <?php
                    } 
                    ?>
```

i want to know where to place the div, and how to continue displaying the items...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please use else condition.please check replace with below code

```
<?php
$counter1 = 0;

//the foreach loop that retrieves the values from the controller    
foreach ($records as $record) {
//an if statement to display the first 4 items..
        ?>
        <?php if($counter1 % 4 == 0) { ?>
            <div style="width:200px; height:200px; float:left; display:inline-block; margin: 0 12.5px 20px 12.5px;">
                <div id="ad_200_200">  
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class='box-scene'>
            <div class='dbox'>
                <div class='front face'>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/newtag.png"></a>
                </div>
                <a style="font-size:15px;" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>music/<?php echo $record->url; ?>">
                    <div class="side face">
                        <span>
                            <?php echo $record->name; ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- this div displays more than once, i dont know where to place it
     for it to display after the first 3 items -->

    <?php
    $counter1++;
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried this, it still displayed the ad more than once

Comment: wooow, thank you so much, it displays perfectly, thanks soo much, one more thing please, how can i continue to display the items, after the first 3 items?

Comment: in which div you want to display ?

Comment: this same div, but after the ad, i want to continue to display the items, because i set 15 per page..

Comment: one minute i understand what you want give me 2 min i am updated with new code

Comment: wooooooooooow!!!... i salute u sire, thanks sooo much, it works like magic!!.. thanks once again, u've saved me a whole lot!

Answer (score 0):

use also an `else` statement like below:

```
<?php
  $counter1 = 0; 
  foreach($records as $record){
    if ($counter1 <= 3){ ?>
              <div class='box-scene'>
                <div class='dbox'>
                   <div class='front face'>
                      <a href="#"><img src="images/newtag.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <a style="font-size:15px;" href="<?php echo base_url();?>music/<?php echo $record->url; ?>">
                       <div class="side face">
                          <span>
                              <?php echo $record->name; ?>
                           </span>
                       </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                 <div>
                  <?php 
                    $counter1++;
                  } else{ ?>
                      <div style="width:200px;height:200px;float:left;display:inline-block; margin: 0 12.5px 20px 12.5px;">
                          <div id="ad_200_200"></div>
                      </div>
                    <?php 
                     $counter1 = 0;
                    } ?>
                <?php
                } 
                ?>
```

Comment: this kinda worked, but it messed up the display, im fixing it now, thanks..